# Changing Joomla component content

Tags: php, joomla

I have been installed a free "Joomla" component and I want to edit that component's relative module content.

For example, I want to change button writing from (for example) "vote" to word in my language like "رای دادن" also I want to remove some unnecessary lines.

I can do my change with inspector but I cant find and change source.

I have search all my site for `<div>` that my content is in it with Dreamweaver but it's not finding anything.

I want to know where that component's contents come from and how can I change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not content, there are language files, you can find more infos [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files) 
Not: You should install your language and set it in backend as default, after this work you should see all default joomla things in your language.